# Keep track of modifications in the objects tree

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, design-patterns

My WPF application shows a tree of objects having some properties. These properties can be modified from the UI via data bindings. Objects themselves can be added or deleted. Nothing special.

The question is: **What's the best way to be aware of changes somewhere in the objects tree?**

Ideas considered so far:

- Create a static method to be called by each object when it is modified
- Create static event on every object type and listen to it
- Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on every object and let them all notify their parents about modifications so I can listen to one event on the objects tree root
- Listen to events from controls like `TextChanged`, `Checked` etc.

They all look like ugly mesh, so I'm afraid to implement anything of them.

Comment: I don't see why the "algorithm" tag is needed for this question.

Comment: The answer may be really general. May be there are common practices used in other languages/frameworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case, comeone will be ever interested, I ended up subclassing all my objects in the tree from the common ancestor responsible for tracking `IsDirty` state and promoting it up and down the tree of objects. I mean that if some object is marked as *dirty* then all it's parents are considered dirty too. And yes, I implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` in this common superclass to be aware of the changes.

Answer (score 2):

INotifyPropertyChanged is probably the best way to go, as it would allow you to bubble up change notifications from any root node.  I guess it would also depend how complex your types are, and what sort of changes you want to react to?

Comment: I want to know only whether there were any changes. Just to enable 'Save' button. Any property change or objects adding/removal are considered as changes.